# New bounties announced but none are available

Tags: borderlands

I'm currently in Arid Badlands and have just completed the arena mission. Claptrap now constantly says that new bounties are available in Fyrestone but the bounty board is red. I can't get any new missions. According to the Wiki, I there are three bounty missions that I haven't done yet.

Is this a glitch or are there other bounty boards Claptrap may refer to?

Comment: Hmm, that does sound quite odd. Are you sure Claptrap is specifically saying the "Fyrestone Bounty Board" and not some NPC? Do you currently have any active missions that you can do (story missions included)? Maybe completing those will open them up (which would suggest the claptrap thing is a bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar thing happen. I found I had to complete some current missions (story or otherwise) in order fo the bounty board to update (despite Claptrap telling me otherwise).

If you open your inventory and go to the quests tab, you can check your currently active quests. It may be that you need to progress the story, or perhaps finish a current bounty quest in order for the missions to show up.

Comment: Yes. Did the story mission and after that, the additional missions showed up.